# Creating a Websocket Interceptor/Manipulator with Java

Tags: java, websocket, proxy, interceptor

I am looking for a way to create a Websocket Interceptor with Java. I want to be able to make my browser connect to it as a proxy and then see all the websocket messages while being in a browser game.

Does anyone know any easy way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you expose http endpoint for that?

Comment: What? I dont really know what you mean

Comment: "I want to be able to make my browser connect to it as a proxy and then see all the websocket messages while being in a browser game" why you can't call your server from a browser by http GET and fetch those messages?